# Open, Refresh and Convert all Word document to PDF in a folder

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am new here but found below to open docx, refresh (linked table from Excel), and save multiple Word document in folder which is working fine.  However I want to add one more procedure to produce PDF format as well before Quit the Document.  So I will have both docx and pdf files in same folder.

Search so much but still cannot find the answer.  Appreciated if you can help…

```
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
MyFolder = "D:\PPM for Dashboard"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.docx")

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile)
        objDoc.Save
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

objWord.Quit
Set objWord = Nothing
```

Comment: Do you have "Microsoft Print to PDF" as an available Printer on your computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method to save a word document as PDF is `ExportAsFixedFormat`. It has numerous parameters, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat) at Microsoft, but basically you just need to provide a filename. If you omit the 2nd parameter (`ExportFormat`), word will check the extension of the filename to decide, however, is does no harm to tell word what you want (use the constant `wdExportFormatPDF`)

The following routine saves an open word doc as PDF in the same folder and with the same name (it assumes that the document itself is already saved, else it don't have a valid file name).

```
Sub saveAsPDF(wordDoc As Word.Document)
    Dim fName As String, p As Integer
    fName = wordDoc.FullName
    p = InStrRev(fName, ".")
    fName = Left(fName, p) & "pdf"
    wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat fName, wdExportFormatPDF
End Sub
```

In your existing loop, you just have to add a call to this procedure:

```
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile)
    objDoc.Save
    saveAsPDF objDoc
    objDoc.Close
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
```

**Update**: The code above uses early binding, so a reference to the Word Object Library is needed. To use late binding (as the OP does), change the routine to:

```
Sub saveAsPDF(wordDoc As Object)
    Const wdExportFormatPDF = 17

    Dim fName As String, p As Integer
    fName = wordDoc.FullName
    p = InStrRev(fName, ".")
    fName = Left(fName, p) & "pdf"
    wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat fName, wdExportFormatPDF
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for help @FunThomas. I have added saveAsPDF objDoc however I am getting "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined"...

Comment: @liu: Haven't noticed that you are using late binding, try the updated version of the Subroutine.